# Is there a process for re-opening or deleting locked questions?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

Specific context: I was looking for a .NET html parser, and google pointed me to [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Locked questions - especially technical locked questions such as the question above - are problematic because they grow stale yet still attract a lot of attention due to their historical votes.  Even comments on the answers to that question are locked; so any user that accidentally visits a page like that has essentially been trapped; and the SO convention to avoid similar questions means the entire topic has lower-quality content due to one historical mistake.

I'm guessing, but the locking process *looks* like it was intended to prevent "bad" questions from gathering too much steam.  It looks to me like that works for questions that are quite off-topic (e.g. "funny anecdotes"-style questions), but for technical questions it seems to me to actually do the reverse: it preserves the unhelpful content at the expense of new content.

For the specific question at hand [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) I'd propose it either get's deleted (at this point, probably best), or reopened (but the content is hopelessly outdated).  In general, I wouldn't mind leaving the "delete" and "reopen" voting systems active for locked questions - if somebody actually looks at those.

Comment: Leaving a historical-locked question open to deletions completely defeats the purpose of the historical lock. That specific option was implemented to pacify veteran users who were upset about their old contributions being deleted.

Comment: I get it; but as said: the current process is counterproductive for technical questions.  Better to leave the question open, that way it can be improved, than this.  Also, if you look at the specific question - this clearly isn't a question that took a lot of care or effort; nor are the top-voted answers thoughtful or particularly valuable.  They're all really basically just links to libraries - that were relevant in 2008(!).